# Where has my Global Search gone?

Tags: ui, global-search, feature-activation

Its  developer org. I have just noticed that there is no global search?

Does anyone know a setting that now can effect this?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a checkbox Setup -> Customize -> Chatter -> Chatter Settings -> Enable that has the explanation:

> Turn on Chatter and Global Search features

Comment: Thanks... actually I realise I knew that now, I though chatter was enabled by default these days.

Comment: @dacology Apparently if you turn Lightning Experience on... https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000JKDuAAO

Comment: Chatter is still off by default in DEs created by the Environment Hub, but it should have been active if you created the DE at developer.salesforce.com.